# Building/Training 1D CNN for sequence-InvalidArgument

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building and training a CNN for a sequence, and have been using RNN's successfully, but am running into issues with CNN.
Here's the code, cnn1 is first (more complex model), tried getting a simpler one to fit and getting errors on both:

The shapes are as follows:

```
xtrain (5206, 19, 4)
ytrain (5206, 4)
xvalid (651, 19, 4)
yvalid (651, 4)
xtest (651, 19, 4)
ytest (651, 4)
```

I've tried just about every combination of kernel sizes and nodes I can think of, tried 2 different model builds.

```
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32, (4), activation='relu'))
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D((4)))
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32, (4), activation='relu'))
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D((4)))
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(32, (4), activation='relu'))
    model_cnn1.add(keras.layers.Dense(4))


    model_cnn2 = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(100,(4),input_shape=(19,4),activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(4),
    keras.layers.Dense(4)
])


    model_cnn2.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics= ['mse','accuracy'])

    model_cnn2.fit(X_train_tf,y_train_tf,epochs=25)
```

Output is 1/25 epochs, not entirely run, then on cnn1 I receive some variation of (final line):

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 4 from 1 for
>   'max_pooling1d_26/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes:
>   [?,1,1,32]

on cnn2 (simpler) I get error (final line):

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,4,4] vs. [32,4]
>   [[{{node metrics_6/mse/SquaredDifference}}]]
>   [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6917]

In general, is there some rule I should be following here for kernels/nodes/etc?  I always seem to get these errors on the shape.
I'm hoping after I build a model of each type I'll understand the ins and outs--no pun intended--but it's driving me crazy!

I've tried every combination of

Answer (score 0):

You can read up on the docs of the `Conv1D` and `MaxPooling1D` to read that these layers change the output shape depending on the value for `strides`. In your case you can keep the output shape for `Conv1D` equal by specifying a padding. `MaxPooling1D` changes the output shape by definition. With `strides = 4`, the output shape will be 4 times smaller in fact. I'd suggest carefully reading the docs to figure out exactly what happens and learning about the underlying theory of CNNs as to why this happens.